# Stopping out of range exceptions for Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Basically I'm drawing on an image and the drawings that I take can sometimes contain elements that don't fit inside of the array that I'm pushing to the screen. I've tried using `numpy.clip` on the arrays before adding adding them in to my main array but this seems far too slow to be acceptable.

Is there any way to just disable the exceptions (the elements that are outside of the range aren't important at all and can be safely lost)? Note that I don't think that I can just catch the exception as that seems to stop the drawing at that point which means that any rows below the one containing an element outside of the screen will just be lost and this is not acceptable.

To further clarify, I have an array representing an output to the screen which matches the starting window resolution. It is width x height and each element specifies the color at that pixel. I'm using a modified version of scikit-image to create circles. These circles may contain points that are outside of the bounds of the screen but I'm drawing them so often that I can't afford the time (at least with `numpy.clip`) required to clean any elements out of the array that are outside of the screen.

I would like to just stop numpy from throwing exceptions when an index out of range exception occurs and instead just continue on with the rest of the array.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you're asking in this question.  One thing that usually helps _a lot_ is adding a snippet of code showing what you've done and then a quick explanation of what you want.

Comment: Hi. You'll get much better help on this problem if you can provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it's hard to advise what's possible or good for your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely should have looked into scikit-image further before asking this, there is a built-in option for specifying the shape of the array that the circle will be drawn to which will stop these exceptions. I apologize for not doing enough research before posting this, I had just become flustered and decided to ask here.

For anyone who might be doing something similar in the future, scikit's shape drawing functions have an optional parameter

> shape : tuple, optional
>
> Image shape which is used to determine the maximum extent of output pixel coordinates. This is useful for ellipses which exceed the image size. By default the full extent of the ellipse are used.